# SharePoint provider hosted App Remote Event Receiver Not Triggring For List item adding event in O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver

I am creating a SharePoint provider-hosted App with event receivers to simply update an item in a SharePoint list `List1` when adding new item in the list.

My App installation event is firing, but no list event fired when adding an item (`SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdding`). Please help.

My `ProcessEvent` Code is here,

```
  public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();
        if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdding)
        {
            if (properties.ItemEventProperties.ListTitle == "List1")
            {
                var title = properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["Title"];
                result.ChangedItemProperties.Add("Title", title + " action by RER");

                result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.Continue;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Remote event receiver `Elements.xml` is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. 
In the app installing event receiver `AppEventReceiver.svc` you need to add the item events to your custom list `List1` .

`ProcessEvent` in `AppEventReceiver.svc` is,

```
 public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();

        using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false))
        {
            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                var customList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List1");
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                // debugging url
                //string opContext = OperationContext.Current.Channel.LocalAddress.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Substring(
                //  0, OperationContext.Current.Channel.LocalAddress.Uri.AbsoluteUri.LastIndexOf("/"));

                //string remoteUrl = string.Format("{0}/RemoteEventReceiver1.svc", opContext);

                // deployment
                string remoteUrl = string.Format("https://{0}/RemoteEventReceiver1.svc",
                 OperationContext.Current.Channel.LocalAddress.Uri.DnsSafeHost + "/services");

                EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation newEventReceiver = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation()
                {
                    EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemAdding,
                    ReceiverName = "RemoteEventReceiver1",
                    ReceiverUrl = remoteUrl,
                    SequenceNumber = 1000
                };

                customList.EventReceivers.Add(newEventReceiver);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Now, in `RemoteEventReceiver1.svc` check the corresponding event type.
`ProcessEvent` in `RemoteEventReceiver1.svc` is,

```
 public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();

        if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdding)
        {
            if (properties.ItemEventProperties.ListTitle == "List1")
            {
                var title = properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["Title"];
                result.ChangedItemProperties.Add("Title", title + " title changed by RER");

                result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.Continue;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

May be this will help someone.